# What is the Google Cloud service equivalent of an HTTPS server?

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, https, google-compute-engine

I have been spinning up compute instances every time I want to host a web page, but I am beginning to wonder if I need a full virtual Apache server just to host some static HTML pages. Is there a cloud service in Google Cloud that could accomplish the same task more efficiently?

I want the site to use my own domain, be HTTPS encrypted, and allow full control of editing the code (I'm not interested in some CMS/WYSIWYG/template). Right now I am using *Cloud DNS* to point the domain to the server, *Apache* as the server, *Let's Encrypt* to make it HTTPS, and SSH when I need to change configuration or upload files to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do static hosting with either Google Cloud Storage, or Firebase Hosting. They're both pretty easy to set up.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting